# Duda al imprimir un dato en un ArrayList

Tags: c#, arraylist

Tengo Este codigo en c# pero al momento en el que elimino un dato de una posición no imprime la suma que deberia ser
Ejemplo Ingreso tres numeros

dato : 1

dato : 2

dato : 3

La suma es: 6

Elimino la posición 0 que tiene el dato 1 pero no imprime el resultdo que deberia ser 5 el metodo que hacer el la eliminacion del dato es el de CambiarDato() y reccori el arrayListe con un for e hice la suma

```
class CCalificaciones
{
    private int a = 0;
    private int b = 0;
    private int op = 0;
    ArrayList datos = new ArrayList();


    public CCalificaciones()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese nuero");
            a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            datos.Add(a);
            b += a;
        }

    }

    public int OP
    {
        get
        {
            Console.WriteLine("--");
            return op;
        }
    }

    public void OPeracion()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("La suma es "+b);
         op = b / 4;

        foreach (var item in datos)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Datos " + item);
        }
    }

    public void CambiarDatos()
    {

            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el dato que desea remover");
            int revom = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            datos.RemoveAt(revom);
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i <datos.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Datos "+datos[i].ToString());
            b+=i;

        }

        Console.WriteLine("La suma es " + i);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

En tu método CambiarDatos, estas usando la variable `i` tanto para iterar como para mostrar la suma al final del for.

Esto provoca que al momento de hacer `b+=i` `b` se sume con el indice del for y no con valor de `datos` en esa posición.

Creo que con esto puede funcionar:

```
public void CambiarDatos()
    {

            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el dato que desea remover");
            int revom = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            datos.RemoveAt(revom);
        int sum = 0;
        for (i = 0; i <datos.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Datos "+datos[i].ToString());
            sum += int.Parse(datos[i])
            //b+=i;

        }

        Console.WriteLine("La suma es " + sum);

    }
```

No se con que objetivo haces: `b+=i` solo ten en consideración que en ese punto `b` puede tener un valor de las operaciones anteriores.